# How to save Azure Pipeline definition (Json) to another git repo

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I wonder if there is a way to save all my pipeline definitions in another git repository outside Azure.

I can see that every change in the pipeline is being versioned, and it gives me the option to compare and revert. However, where is it being saved? Can I set up a git repo outside of Azure to control it?

Diego

Answer (score 1):

The very idea behind YAML pipelines is the **ability of versioning the pipeline definition in a git repo**.

I would suggest for you to try to switch to YAML pipelines, that's what they were created for. If you're using classic pipelines, most of actions / steps can be transformed into YAML easily.

Answer (score 0):

Since Azure DevOps is a cloud offering service. Your data is cloud-hosted.

For Azure Pipeline definition (Json), you could manually download it from Azure DevOps UI and store it locally.

You could not use Git Repo to control the pipeline definition.

Answer (score 0):

It's stored in the SQL database that stores most stuff in Azure DevOps. It's not in a user serviceable location. You can use the [REST API to read build definition revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get-definition-revisions?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511). And you can store the output whereever you want. You can use the [Update API to update the build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511).

The "new style" YAML pipelines are stored in human readable text in your Git Repository. You can version and manage the repository from there with ease.